# Kotlin capture image and store it locally

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hey guys I build an android app, where I want to capture some (1-3) images and save them for some time. How could I do this. I already thought of doing it with SharedPreferences what would be absolutely perfect because I already use that for Strings an Ints in my app.
There are plenty tutorials out there but somehow nothing exactly hits my needs.

I would be super grateful if you could help out with that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store images in your application folder (Access app-specific file)

```
val file = File(context.filesDir, yourImageFileName)
```

store the filename in your sharedPref and room database

Guide :-
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: alright thanks i will try that